# setting a delay after a form is submitted before it can be submitted again

Tags: jquery

Comment form is submitted on keypress (enter), but I need to set a delay/cooldown on it, so it can't be submitted over and over again.

```
$( document ).on('keypress', '#default_add_comment_form textarea, #default_add_comment_form input', function( event ){
    if ( event.keyCode == '13' ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#default_add_comment_form').submit();
    }
});
```

I tried Jquery's 'delay' method, as in `$('#default_add_comment_form').delay(5000).submit();` but it doesn't work.

The answer suggested below doesn't seem to work.

```
    $( document ).on('keypress', '#default_add_comment_form textarea, #default_add_comment_form input', function( event ){
        if ( event.keyCode == '13' ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#default_add_comment_form').submit();
            $('#default_add_comment_form input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#default_add_comment_form input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}, 50000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after `$('#default....').submit();`

```
$('#default_add_comment_form input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#default_add_comment_form input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
}, _your_interval_in_milliseconds_);
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. (Yes I changed _your_interval... to 5000 :P ).

Comment: no way this doesn't work, only if your submit button is not type submit

Comment: yes, that is correct, can you put your html (only form html, including form tag)

Comment: I will do this when I get to my computer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

On submit, add a listener which intercepts future submits and displays a message. When it's timed out, remove the listener.